# Delete commit and unmerge

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I made a commit and push that includes a merge. It results in many errors so I want to roll back all the changes. I want to delete last pushed commit and return the origin to the highlighted commit. Here is the image that describes the problem.

[image: Commit and merge]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: @phd I think he wants to know how to solve it using sourcetree rather than the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have push rights:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: This will work but if you are working on a repository where other developers are also working, it is considered a very bad idea, as it can screw up other people's history in their copies of the repository.

Comment: yes doing this on a shared repo is a bad idea. In that case, pushing a revert commit is better.